# The best way to share volume with config data between multiple Docker containers

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have Docker image which contains config files of VirtualBox and I want to use this image for running multiple containers in parallel.

Config files of VM are being stored on host OS, however, I am afraid of issues with config data of VMs which may occur because of parallel accessing by multiple containers. All containers will be started by Jenkins automatically.

Therefore, could you please tell what is the best way to share data between containers to avoid data corruption because of parallel usage?

Comment: What's going to be writing to the config files?

Comment: There will be VirtualBox\ VMs folder with VM files: *.vbox *.vbox-prev *.vmdk etc

Comment: Just look at the documentation of Persistence volume in Docker using Portworx. They have the good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount your volumes [read-only](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume)

Comment: Yes, but in this case, I have a doubt that VM will be started because I do there: vagrant up; vagrant suspend.

Comment: Do you launch VMs in docker containers? Sounds odd. But if, you **must not share**  your vbox files. Instead make your image contain them physically (COPY in Dockerfile)

Comment: Those files are being built in the container based on the 1st image which is being built from Dockerfile and in which  I install all necessary components. Aftermath I commit container and build another image which will allow starting containers in parallel. With using COPY I'll need to create another Dockerfile and build the 3rd image with COPYing files. It will complicate the task and will not solve my problem as long as it will affect the second image.